# Does sometimes [] is optional?

Tags: c#

I have a simple code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object[] v1 = FuncBunja1();
        Object v3 = FuncBunja1();

        v1[0].ToString();
        (v3 as Object[])[0].ToString();
    }

    private static Object[] FuncBunja1()
    {
        Object[] objs = new Object[4];

        return objs;
    }
}
```

How compiler let to v3 get pointer to array? Is shall be reference to single Object by declaration (as i understand).

From memory side i can see, that v1 and v3 contains addresses of arrays of Objects

Comment: Every object is an `Object` in `C#` and can be casted to this type.

Comment: An array is an Object, so there's nothing wrong with an Object reference pointing to an array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z4khca9.aspx

Comment: In a nutshell, instance or variable of type `Object[]` is an instance of Array class whose base class is object so compiler would allow this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because types in C# usually inherit from `Object`, in particular `Object[]`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) states (**although not 100% accurate**):

> In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object.  You can assign values of any type to variables of type object.

As **@RonanThibaudau** commented, there are some exceptions, see [Not everything derives from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx). Nevertheless:

> A great many types do derive from object. All value types, including enums and nullable types, derive from object. All class, array and delegate types derive from object.

Comment: Not all types inherit from object (it's not important here but i feel it's worth pointing out as there are exceptions and it's often miss stated). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any type in .Net inherits from `Object`, hence as an example:

- the type `Object[]` inherits from `Object` accordingly.
- the type `int` inherits from `Object`.
- the type `int[]` inherits from `Object`.

However to clarify the OP, the type `int[]` does NOT inherit from `int`.